# How to go one level up from the GetCurrentDirectory() path in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi

Using the `GetCurrentDirectory()` function, I am getting the current directory path like below:

```
C:\PCPE\src\PCPEJob
```

My requirement is, from the `GetCurrentDirectory()` path I need to go one level up, ie `C:\PCPE\src`, so that I can append a new directory to this path.

How can I go one level up from the `GetCurrentDirectory()` path?

Comment: Just append `"/.."` to the path. `..` is one level up.

Comment: Unclear if you want to change the current directory, but if that is the case then `SetCurrentDirectory("..");` as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setcurrentdirectory

Comment: [PathCchRemoveFileSpec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/pathcch/nf-pathcch-pathcchremovefilespec) could also help.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`PathCombine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathcombinew) or related function, which can append a relative path to another path, eg:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>

TCHAR path[MAX_PATH] = {};
GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, path);
PathCombine(path, path, TEXT("..\\newFolder"));
// use new path as needed...
```